# jQuery onclick doesn't work on a button with data-toggle and data-target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT** : I use Bootstrap as well. No console errors

I have a button which hides and un-hides a div

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" id="showBtnFullDetails" data-target="#showFullDetails" value="Dynamic">Show Responses</button>
```

and the Div

```
<div id="showFullDetails" class="collapse out">Some Data</div>
```

Then I have this onclick event

```
$("#showBtnFullDetails").click(function() {
  alert("Test");
});
```

But it doesn't work. On other buttons it works. Is there some explation to this? I need this button to work to hide and unhide that div as well I need it to accept onclick function coz I'll be doing other task.

Comment: does the console say anything?

Comment: No errors. The hide and unhide works fine as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7dqhvxzm/ it is working?

Comment: @jackjop I'm with Bootstrap Sir.

Comment: placing script anywhere below the button might work

Comment: I know you're bootstrap but what does it have to do with click event not working?

Comment: @jackjop I dunno. It just doesn't work :(

Comment: can you post the code around this click handler plz?

Comment: Sure. You didn't include jquery library. and your function come inside Dom ready

Comment: Is the ID unique? Is the element already present at runtime? There are so many possible ways things could go wrong, that's why we **always** encourage users to create a [minimal, verifiable and concrete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is your jQuery code running at the end of the page or within a document ready handler?

Comment: Guys, I think I know the problem now. I forgot to mention that the button is  dynamically generated and not hard coded. So the problem might be the onclick event loads first before the button even appears or created.

Comment: Use @epascarello solution for dynamically generated button it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event delegation and see if that catches it.

```
$(document).on("click", "#showBtnFullDetails", function() {
  alert("Test");
});
```

Or I believe there is a shown event

```
$("#showFullDetails").on("show.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse",function(event){
    alert("Test");
});
```

Comment: Worked perfect :) Thanks!