# Data-toggle and onclick doesn't work together and i'm too new to apply @epascarello 's solution to

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

i have a problem a little bit like this one :

[jQuery onclick doesn't work on a button with data-toggle and data-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747340)

But i can't apply the solution from @epascarello to my problem

I'm using bootstrap and I want to add a collapse and an onclick action on the same   < a>

```
<a class="control" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"onclick="play('audioPlayer', this)">
```

If I delete the data-toggle part, the onclick works, and if i delete the onclick part, the data-toggle works,

Could anyone help me ?

Thank you :)

Comment: @epascarello will you be my savior

Comment: why cant you use delegated event as mentioned in epascarello answer

Comment: Yes but i don't understand how to apply this to my code :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First give a id to your `a tag`

```
<a id="YourID" class="control" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#demo"onclick="play('audioPlayer', this)">
```

and than your JS

```
$(document).on("click", "#YourID", function() {
  alert("Test");
});
```

Try this first

This is called delegated event handlers .You can refer to: http://api.jquery.com/on/

**EXPLANATION**

With delegated event handlers, you attach your `event handlers` to the `parent` element that exists at the time we run the code (it's `document` in this case). When the child elements are clicked (**no event handlers**), the event is bubbled up by browser and is **handled** by its parent (**with event handlers attached**)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers

Comment: Now learn about delegated handler ... how it works ,, i am writing some description ok

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, ALL THE F*****G MORNING TO ACHIEVE THIS, THANKS!

Comment: @Aker666 glad to know that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly in vanilla JS:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#name_ref" data-toggle="tab" id="name_id">My Tab Label</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

later...

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="name_ref">
    <div class="panel-heading">Content</div>
</div>
```

later...

```
<script>
    document
    .getElementById("name_id")
    .addEventListener("click", function(event) { console.log("event");});
</script>
```