# bootstrap dropdown not working with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap

So I am creating my blog with Django and I am developing the notification system. I want when the user click the drop to mark all notifications as seen its working and every thing is working fine but when I add the Ajax the dropdown stop working but the Ajax works fine I tried changing the script position in HTML but nothing.

**Using**

- bootstrap 3.3.7 locally
- jquery

the ajax :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#n_d").click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'seen' %}",
             success: function(){
                document.getElementById("mcount").innerHTML = 0
             }
        });
        return false;
   });

});
</script>
```

the dropdown (it's inside a navbar)

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
         <li class="dropdown">
         {% notifications request as notifications %}
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="n_d" onclick="return x=1" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-inbox "> <span class="label label-info" id="mcount">{% noticount request %}</span></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          {% load blog_tags %}

          {% for notification in notifications %}
              <li>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><div class="notify-img"><img src="https://www.awn.com/sites/default/files/styles/userthumbnail_tiny/public/avatar92.jpg?itok=i7013HnC" alt=""></div></div>
                  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 pd-l0"><a href="{% url 'detail' notification.post_pk %}">{{ notification.FromUser }}&nbsp;{{ notification.content }}</a></div>
                </li>
          {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
```

> the weird tags are Django stuff.

Comment: Any js errors? Did you inspect your DOM? You really need to debug it step by step

Comment: thanks for your response, yes i did every thing looks good

Comment: I think I found the problem now that I double checked your code! Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an error in your code! I can understand that you copy-pasted some stuff because it is not very consistent.

You are having this `onclick="return x=1" data-toggle="dropdown"` and you are listening for another `onClick` event in the jQuery script above.

By having this you are overwriting the initial object `onclick` and probably conflict with the `toggle="dropdown"` which triggers the menu to open.

You should try a different implementation there.

Try to hack it by removing `data-toogle="dropdown"` and add `$($(this).data("target")).modal("show");` instead of `return false` in your ajax code.

Comment: thank you, i removed the onclick but still not working

Comment: actually i added the onclick because i thought it will solve the problem : | i hate copy-paste people code, so what is the problem

Comment: Yes exactly the onclick was not the only problem. If you remove the jQuery onClick it is going to work right? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034394/data-toggle-and-onclick-doesnt-work-together-and-im-too-new-to-apply-epascare

Comment: i am so soryy for asking a lot, but what to do!

Comment: try to hack it by removing `data-toogle="dropdown"` and add `$($(this).data("target")).modal("show");`  instead of `return false` in your ajax code.

Comment: Check your console for possible errors and try to fix them if exist

Comment: it worked thank you so much please update your question so i can upvote it

Comment: Glad that I helped you! Have fun!